# How to handle KeyboardException raised in threading module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, macos, sockets

I'm creating a server using the `socket` and `threading` module. The server allows for multiple connections to be made. I've been doing some error handling (as shown in the code below). However, there is one error that I cannot figure out how to handle.

**Code (server.py):**

```
import socket
import threading
# import pyaudio
# import json
from os import system

system('clear')

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5000
buffer_size = 2048
connected_clients = {}


# Thread for listening and accepting new connections
def client_listener():
    while True:
        try:
            # Accepts new client
            connection, address = server_socket.accept() 

            # Creates a new thread for each connected client
            handle_client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(connection, address))
            handle_client_thread.start()
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            pass
        except OSError:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass


# Handles each connected client in a separate thread
def handle_client(client, client_address):
    try:
        # Receives room number
        room_number = client.recv(buffer_size).decode('utf-8')
        print(f'\nConnection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} ({room_number})')

        # Adds new client to 'connected_clients'
        connected_clients[room_number] = client
        print(connected_clients)

        while True:
            data = client.recv(buffer_size).decode('utf-8')
            # If no data is received, close the socket
            if not data:
                print(f'{client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} ({room_number}) Disconnected')
                connected_clients.pop(room_number)
                break
            # Print received data
            else:
                print(f'{client_address[0]} ({room_number}): {data}')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        client.close()
        connected_clients.pop(room_number)


with socket.socket() as server_socket:
    try:
        # Prevents [Errno 48: Address already in use]
        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        # Binds socket to host and port
        server_socket.bind((host, port))
        server_socket.listen()
        print(f'Server hosted on {host}:{port}')

        # Starts new thread for listening for new clients
        client_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_listener, name=client_listener)
        client_listener_thread.start()

        # Prevents main thread from closing
        while True:
            pass
    except socket.error as error_message:
        print(str(error_message))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(': Closing server...\n')
        pass
```

The error message is raised when I close the server with a keyboard interrupt (^C). When I first press ^C, the server is closed. However, the second ^C seems to raise an exception within the `threading` module.

**Error message:**

```
Server hosted on 10.108.249.108:5000
^C: Closing server...

^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1273, in _shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1032, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1048, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How would I go about handling this KeyboardInterrupt in a seamless way such that the program is closed without errors on a single ^C? The desired result would be having the server close the connections with each connected client, close the threads, then finally shut down the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you press `Ctrl-C` on your keyboard while your script is running on the console, you send a `SIGINT` to the script process. You can use the `signal` python module to handle such signals:

```
import signal
import sys
def my_sig_handler(sig, frame):
        print('Received interrupt signal')
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_sig_handler) # Register your signal handler for SIGINT
```

Once you do this, any time your running script receives an interrupt signal, `my_sig_handler` will be called. There are several kinds of signals defined in Linux, and it is generally a good idea to add signal handlers in your code for some of the common ones, so that it can clean up and exit gracefully.

More information about signals [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Comment: +1 This is it. Your answer help me realise that it was because I removed the signal handler that a piece of code that had been responding well to CRTL-C suddenly started throwing the KeyboardInterrupt Traceback to console. All attempts at surrounding code blocks with try..catch KeyboardInterrupt failed.